# Jenkins erases jobs on system restart

Tags: linux, jenkins, redhat

I am running Jenkins with

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

from the `/usr/lib/jenkins` directory on RedHat Server 6.7 (Santiago).  I am also running Jenkins in the background (I think); I set this up with `nohup`.  Whenever I restart Jenkins or the VM, all of the jobs get erased.  It seems like Jenkins is resetting itself.

I guess it has something to do with the command I use to start it up.  So I have two questions:

1. How can I set up Jenkins to where it saves its workspace instead of deleting it after each time it or the system is bounced.
2. How can I setup Jenkins to run in the background, and set it up to start at system startup time?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a JENKINS_HOME variable to define your Jenkins workspace.

To install Windows as a service, you can follow this guide:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions

Or this one:
http://justinsilver.com/technology/linux/install-jenkins-centos-service/